# Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 21980 of the JSON data

Tags: angularjs, json, web-services

I'm using angularjs http Post call to get info from ASMX service.

I'm Calling ASMX service as following:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'FileService.asmx/GetSearchResults',
                data: JSON.stringify({ fso: fileSearchOptions }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json"
            })
           .then(successCallBack, errorCallBack);
```

Returning response as follows:

```
List<File> filesList = new List<File>();

            if (response != null && response.FileSearchResults != null)
            {
                foreach (var f in response.FileSearchResults)
                {
                    File file = new File();
                    file.FileID = f.FileID;
                    file.FileNumber = f.FileNum;
                    file.OpenDate = f.OpenDate != null ? f.OpenDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty;
                    file.CreationDate = f.CreationDate != null ? f.CreationDate.Value.ToShortDateString() : string.Empty;
                    file.RegionName = f.RegionName;
                    file.FileStatus = f.StatusCD;
                    file.Address = f.Address;

                    filesList.Add(file);
                }
            }

            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(filesList));
```

I'm not able to identify where exactly i'm trying to parse the already parsed data. Please correct me where I'm wrong.

Error I'm Getting is :

Error: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 21980 of the JSON data

Thanks In Advance !!!

Comment: Can you post the data that you are receiving?

Comment: Response From  Service Call:[{"FileID":37673188,"FileNumber":"803599-59","CreationDate":"10/5/2016","OpenDate":"10/5/2016","RegionName"
:"National Commercial Services Division","FileStatus":"Open","Address":"Westlake Condos West Des Moines
 Dallas IA USA"}]{"d":null}

Comment: If i dont pass the data param in request and remove the param from Service method, its working fine. With params its throwing error

Comment: Because you have mentioned the content-type header, you do not need to do it again in data params.

Comment: if I dont to JSON.stringify, Its not even calling the web service method. I'm getting following error : "Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: object.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer